# Sybase 12: REGEXP search condition not understood

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql, sybase

I'm using Sybase 12.5.3, and want/need to do regex pattern matching.

The Sybase help says that regex features have been there since version 11, but I cannot get anything to work.

[This document](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere/dbreference_en11/rf-sqllanguage-s-4915351.html) describes the REGEXP and SIMILAR TO search conditions.  I have tried both of these with no success, on various tables.

As an example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM REPORTS 
 WHERE name regexp '.*'
```

...gives me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'regexp'.

The only search results for that error are related to MS-SQL.

I've tried various things, including using REGEXP_LIKE and SIMILAR TO, but I get the same sort of error, as if that word is not understood.  Am I missing something?  The column I'm comparing contains strings.

I can't find any option to enable/disable these features either, and the actual string I'm supplying has no bearing on it.

I'm using DBArtisan 8.7.5 if that's relevant.

Comment: In case regex isn't supported, what are you trying to search for?  LIKE does support limited wildcarding.

Comment: Shouldn't **name** be inside square brackets? I think that's a reserved word.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I was trying to emulate business logic handled by a Java server over this DB, to create extracts.  There are some very complex regular expressions in there, and some 'meta' relationships between entities can be inferred from the expressions.  LIKE wouldn't cut it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your link goes to a Sybase Anywhere manual but the 12.5.3 you are using? Well that looks like a Sybase ASE version number. Totally different products - I don't think ASE supported Regex till ASE 15. If you are using ASE you'll need to find a different way to do this.

Comment: Ah, that must be it.  I'm new to Sybase so didn't realise that there was more than one RDBMS they offer.  I had searched quite in depth for Sybase regex, and all results indicated it was possible.  I've checked and we are indeed using ASE - a shame that we can't use regexps then.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `like` instead of a function and provide a regular-expression-like
character class matching - e.g. `name like "[0-9]"`

See the docs: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1520/html/iqrefbb/CACGCGGC.htm

Comment: +1: Initially downvoted, but turns out that `like` does have a (very limited) functionality which resembles regex. Edited this in.

Answer (score 0):

It could be `regexp('.*')`, but after looking at the Sybase manual for 12.5.x, I don't think that version has a regexp method.